# How to publish Gradle project to MavenLocal that depends on another local project

Tags: maven, gradle, publish, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on an Android library, but this is most likely not Android specific.

I have a library project (`mylib`), that depends on another library project (`myotherlib`). Now if I publish my project to `mavenLocal`, and try to depend on it, I get this error:

```
   > Could not find mylib:myotherlib:0.1.0.
```

So this transitive dependency doesn't get included, it appears, also it is treated as if it's one of `mylib`'s modules. So is there a way to include `myotherlib`'s code when publishing `mylib`?

This is `mylib`'s build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
plugins {
   ...
   id("maven-publish")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.my.company.mylib"

    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }

    publishing {
        singleVariant("release") {
            withSourcesJar()
            withJavadocJar()
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("release") {
        groupId = "com.my.company"
        artifactId = "mylib"
        version = properties["version"] as String
        afterEvaluate {
            from(components["release"])
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  
    api(project(":myotherlib"))
}
```

And `myotherlib`'s location is referenced in `settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "mylib"

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

include(
    ":library",
    ":myotherlib"
)

project(":myotherlib").projectDir = File(rootProject.projectDir, "../myotherlib/library")
```

Publishing to the local Maven repo is done by running `./gradlew mylib:publishToMavenLocal`.